# SessionContext.getBusinessObject() in EJB3 & JNDI lookup

Tags: ejb, jndi

In **EJB2**, one needed to use *getEJBBusinessObject()* method in a EJB to pass reference to itself when calling another (local/remote) bean.

Does the same apply for **EJB3**?

e.g.

```
@Stateless 
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal { 

    @Resource private SessionContext sessionContext; 

    public void myMethod() { 
        OtherBeanLocal  otherBean = ...; // getting reference to other local EJB. 
        MyBeanLocal myBean =  sessionContext.getBusinessObject(MyBeanLocal.class); 
        b.aMethod(myBean); 
    } 

    // Edit: calling myMethodTwo() from inside of myMethodOne()
    public void myMethodOne() {  
        MyBeanLocal myBean =  sessionContext.getBusinessObject(MyBeanLocal.class); 
        myBean.myMethodTwo(); 
    } 

    public void myMethodTwo() { 
        ...
    } 
    ... 
}
```

Also, if I fetch my local bean using *getBusinessObject()* method, is it the same as if I use common *JNDI lookup*?

I've tested both approach, and both work, but I'm not sure if bean object is processed the same way by the container.

**Edit**:
Is fetching the reference to ejb itself, when calling myMethodTwo() from inside myMethodOne() of the same ejb, in EJB3, still needed? Is it allowed to call methods inside the same ejb through **this** reference?
How will this address transactions, if I decide to use some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the same applies to EJB 3.  Yes, getBusinessObject is the EJB 3 analog to getEJBObject (or getEJBLocalObject).  All of those methods return a proxy for the current bean object.  For stateless session beans, this is basically the same as looking up through JNDI, though it's likely to perform better since it avoids JNDI overhead.

Comment: Thanx for quick response! Actually I'm caching my JNDI lookups, so I think I'll stick with this approach, instead of fetching ejbs with getBusinessObject()... Do I need to follow the same approach (fetching ejb instance of the ejb itself), when calling one method, from inside another method in the same ejb. (I've updated my question accordingly)

Comment: Yes, you must use getBusinessObject if you want EJB semantics.  The proxy returned from that method is responsible for transaction, security, interceptors, etc.